# How to aggregate certain arrays in a multi-dimensional array?

Tags: ruby

I have a nested array and need to aggregate inner arrays that are equal except for their last elements, in the manner shown below.

```
_array = [["Nokia","Review","3"], ["Nokia","Review","2"],
          ["Samsung","Review","4"], ["Apple","Review","4"],
          ["Apple","Review","3"]]
```

Desired output:

```
[["Nokia","Review","5"], ["Samsung","Review","4"], ["Apple","Review","7"]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One liner, just for fun:

```
_array.group_by{ |e| e.first(2) }
      .transform_values { |v| v.sum { |e| e.last.to_i } }
      .map { |k, v| k << v.to_s }

#=> [["Nokia", "Review", 5], ["Samsung", "Review", 4], ["Apple", "Review", 7]]
```

---

Some steps to help understanding

```
_array.group_by{ |e| e.first(2) }
#=> {["Nokia", "Review"]=>[["Nokia", "Review", "3"],["Nokia", "Review", "2"]],
#    ["Samsung", "Review"]=>[["Samsung", "Review", "4"]],
#    ["Apple", "Review"]=>[["Apple", "Review", "4"], ["Apple", "Review", "3"]]}

_array.group_by{ |e| e.first(2) }.transform_values { |v| v.sum { |e| e.last.to_i } }
#=> {["Nokia", "Review"]=>5, ["Samsung", "Review"]=>4, ["Apple", "Review"]=>7}
```

Then `map`.

Comment: Can you tell me little about transform _values

Comment: @RobertThomas, I guess official Docs is better than me: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values ;)

Answer (score 3):

That's a really odd form, as the numbers are strings, but you can just accumulate with a bit of conversion:

```
array = [["Nokia","Review","3"], ["Nokia","Review","2"], ["Samsung","Review","4"], ["Apple","Review","4"], ["Apple","Review","3"]]

# Define a tabulator Hash defaulting to count of 0
array.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |a,h|
  # Use the first two elements of the array as the key
  h[a[0,2]] += a[2].to_i
end.map do |k, v|
  # Convert back to string value, combining key and count
  k + [ v.to_s ]
end

# => [["Nokia", "Review", "5"], ["Samsung", "Review", "4"], ["Apple", "Review", "7"]]
```

As you can see this would be a lot easier if the data was in a different form, or even if the numbers were actually integers.

Comment: Maybe `h[a[0..-2]]` in case inner arrays have other than three elements or are not all the same size (or in future that could be the case). As you well-know, you could alternatively write `... h[a[0..-2]] = (h[a[0..-2]].to_i + a[-1].to_i).to_s; end.values`. It's slightly less efficient but avoids the need to convert integers to strings at the end.